# nodejs orm many to many

Tags: node.js, node-orm2

Hello Im trying to do associaton with many to many in node using [`node-orm2`](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2).

I have this tables:

- `project` --> id, name
- `user` --> id, name
- `user_project` --> user_fk, project_fk (this is many to many association table)

The controller returns me a list of users and a list of projects, but i need to return in a both another property with projects of every user and users of every prject.

Models:

```
module.exports = function (orm, db) {
    var Project = db.define('project', {
            name     : { type: 'text', required: true }
        },
        {
            methods: {
                serialize: function () {
                    return {
                        id        : this.id,
                        name     : this.name
                    };
                }
            }
        });
};


module.exports = function (orm, db) {
    var User = db.define('user', {
            name     : { type: 'text', required: true },
            email     : { type: 'text', required: true }
        },
        {
            methods: {
                serialize: function () {
                    return {
                        id        : this.id,
                        name     : this.name,
                        email     : this.email
                    };
                }
            }
        });
};
```

Controller:

```
module.exports = {

    list: function (req, res, next) {

        req.models.project.find().limit(4).order('-created').all(function (err, messages) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            var projects = messages.map(function (m) {
                return m.serialize();
            });
            console.log(projects);
        });

        req.models.user.find().limit(4).order('-created').all(function (err, messages) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            var users = messages.map(function (m) {
                return m.serialize();
            });
            console.log(users);
        });
        res.sendfile(settings.path + '/public/index2.html');
    }
```

How can I do this I'm confused, I readed the documentation but i don't understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Had some issues with node-orm also...
You can do it with light-orm or bookshelf.js.

In light-orm you can simply extend model with complex request like this:

```
var SiteCollection = new ORM.Collection({
    connector: ORM.driver,
    tableName: 'site',
    modelExtension: {
        getAds: function(callback) {
            var query = "SELECT DISTINCT `ads`.* FROM `ads` INNER JOIN `siteads` " +
                "ON `ads`.`id` = `siteads`.`ads_id` " +
                "WHERE site_id = " + this.get('id');
            ORM.Collections.AdsCollection.find(query, callback);
        },
        renderAds: function(callback) {
            var that = this;
            this.getAds(function(err, ads) {
                var html = ejs.render(adsTemplate, {
                    content: new ORM.Collection(ads).toJSON()
                });
                fs.writeFileSync(writeDir + that.get('id') + ".html", html, {
                    encoding: 'utf8'
                });
                callback();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Try it: https://npmjs.org/package/light-orm